# How to write an RSS feed with Java?

Tags: java, rss, rome

I'm using Java, and need to generate a simple, standards-compliant RSS feed. How can I go about this?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I recommend using [Rome](http://rometools.github.io/rome/RssAndAtOMUtilitiEsROMEV0.5AndAboveTutorialsAndArticles/RssAndAtOMUtilitiEsROMEV0.5TutorialUsingROMEToCreateAndWriteASyndicationFeed.html):

```
// Feed header
SyndFeed feed = new SyndFeedImpl();
feed.setFeedType("rss_2.0");
feed.setTitle("Sample Feed");
feed.setLink("http://example.com/");

// Feed entries
List entries = new ArrayList();
feed.setEntries(entries);

SyndEntry entry = new SyndEntryImpl();
entry.setTitle("Entry #1");
entry.setLink("http://example.com/post/1");
SyndContent description = new SyndContentImpl();
description.setType("text/plain");
description.setValue("There is text in here.");
entry.setDescription(description);
entries.add(entry);

// Write the feed to XML
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
new SyndFeedOutput().output(feed, writer);
System.out.println(writer.toString());
```

Comment: That seems like a dead project now. The example won't even compile!

Comment: Rome uses java classes from com.sun.syndication.* package. This solution is too old now.

Comment: It is really old now? Are there any other alternatives?

Comment: In 2023 this seems to work just fine. I just used it with java17 and compiles and runs perfectly. The maven package moved and 2.x requires at least java 8
com.rometools:rome:2.1.0