# RSS lib for java

Tags: java, rss, parsing

Advise any rss parser for java,which support much formats.
I am using informa,but informa very slow for GAE

Comment: all roads lead to rome, etc etc

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113063/java-rss-library?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

[rome](https://rometools.jira.com/wiki/display/ROME/Home) is a tool for dealing with RSS feeds.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you do not require any specific library for rss. Just consider them as xmls. All the magic resides with the RSSReader.

If you need rss jars you can download from here
http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javaserverpages/rss_utilities/rss_utils_1.1.zip