# extract URL with jsoup

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup

I'm trying to extract some url of a web page but I cant. Could you help me

```
String url = "http://www.cadenaser.com/rssaudio/larguero.html";
```

Elements etiqueta = doc.getElementsByTag("guid");
        System.out.println("ETIQUETA GUID " + etiqueta.toString());

```
    for (Element guids : etiqueta) {
              result.add(guids.toString());
              String urlssss = guids.absUrl("guid");
               System.out.println("CadenoooNNNNN ESSSSS " + urlssss);

              }
```

I only would like to get the urls:
strin1= http://www.cadenaser.com/cadenaser/podcast/audios/cadenaser_larguero_20110304csrcsrdep_1_Aes.mp3
string2=http://www.cadenaser.com/cadenaser/podcast/audios/cadenaser_larguero_20110304csrcsrdep_1_Aes.mp3
......

Any help? Many thanks and sorry for my english!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try using a [Java RSS Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113063/java-rss-library), such as [Rome](http://java.net/projects/rome/)