# splitting up of xml file using java

Tags: java, xml, split

> < ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"? > 
>    < rss xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:ynews="http://news.yahoo.com/rss/" version="2.0" >  < channel >
>
> < title>Cricket News Headlines | Cricket News - Yahoo! News India< /title>
>
> < link>http://in.news.yahoo.com/cricket/< /link>
>
> < description>Check out the latest Cricket news headlines from Yahoo! News India. Find top Cricket stories and in-depth coverage of
>   Cricket news from India and around the world.< /description>
>
> < language>en-IN< /language>
>
> < copyright>Copyright (c) 2011 Yahoo! Inc. All rights reserved< /copyright>
>
> < pubDate>2011-04-06T15:30:02+05:30< /pubDate>
>
> < ttl>5< /ttl>
>
> < image>
>
> < title>Cricket News Headlines | Cricket News - Yahoo! News India< /title>
>
> < link>http://in.news.yahoo.com/cricket/< /link>
>
> < url>http://l.yimg.com/os/mit/media/m/index/img/Yahoo_logo_en-
>   IN.gif< /url>
>
> < /image>
>   < item>< title>Hectic schedule will drain players, says Dhoni< /title>
>
> < description>Chennai, Apr 6 (PTI) ...< /description>
>
> < link>http://in.news.yahoo.com/hectic-schedule-drain-players-says-dhoni-20110406-023100-889.html< /link>
>
> < pubDate>2011-04-06T09:31:00Z< /pubDate>
>
> < source>PTI< /source>
>
> < guid isPermaLink="false">/hectic-schedule-drain-players-says-dhoni-20110406-023100-889.html< /guid>
>
> < /item>
>
> < item>
>
> < title>India, Pakistan trade secretaries to meet on April 27-28< /title>
>
> < description>New Delhi, Apr 6 (PTI)  ...< /description>
>
> < link>http://in.news.yahoo.com/india-pakistan-trade-secretaries-meet-april-27-28-20110406-023100-140.html< /link>

I want only the HEADLINES  from this XML, that is only between < item>< title>MESSAGES< /title> tags.  Also have to print the message one after other continuously. how can i do this.

Comment: http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/javax.xml.parsers/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java.html

Comment: You want to parse an RSS feed? Check out the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113063/java-rss-library

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use the [`javax.xml.xpath`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html) APIs that are included in Java SE 5 for this.

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

        FileReader reader = new FileReader("input.xml");
        InputSource xml = new InputSource(reader);
        NodeList titleNodes = (NodeList) xPath.evaluate("//item/title", xml, XPathConstants.NODESET);

        for(int x=0; x<titleNodes.getLength(); x++) {
            System.out.println(titleNodes.item(x).getTextContent());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: i have to read the live datas every 5 minutes and print it, how can i do that.i can't able to store it in a file.

Comment: @tr_tech - You can create an InputSource on any type of InputStream or Reader.  You can also pass other input types such as DOM nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Parse the file to create a DOM document. On this DOM select all `title` elements and their text contents are the headlines you're looking for.

Quick example with `dom4j`:

```
File xml = new File("input.xml");     // replace with your document
SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
Document doc = reader.read(xml);
List titles = doc.selectNode("//item/title");  // a list of all title elements
for (Object obj:titles) 
   System.out.println(((Element) obj).getText());
```

Should print all titles to the console

Comment: Using the standard javax.xml.xpath libraries you do not need to materialize the XML as a DOM first:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566124/splitting-up-of-xml-file-using-java/5566161#5566161

Answer (score 0):

This is something that comes up often. I have a groovy script to do this. It is available here.

https://github.com/ramanathanrv/utils/blob/master/groovy/split_xml.groovy

Usage: groovy split_xml.groovy <input_file_name> <no_of_pieces>

PS: This is not my code. I got this code from somewhere but really forgot the source.