# JAXB unmarshaling Ignoring the SOAP Envelope/Header tags

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb

I have a client I am building for accessing a web service. I am using some JAXB generated classes(Netbeans 6.9) to unmarshal my xml data.

I am getting unexpected element errors when trying to unmarshal the InputStream response from this webservice, I also get the same unexpected element error if I save the response to a file.

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope", local:"Envelope"). Expected elements are <{http://www.cmicdataservices.com/}Authentication>,....
```

With the data saved to file I can go in and delete the SOAP tags(envelope,body,headr) and then run the unmarshaling with no problem.

I have not really found a way to make the unmarshaling ignore these tags.  Does anyone know what can be done to ignore those tags?

Here is the main method and the class returned by the stream.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = null;
        try {
            CMICData cmic = new CMICData();
            jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("cmic.ajrs.com");
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();


            GetCurrentDataVer1Response response = (GetCurrentDataVer1Response)
                    unmarshaller.unmarshal( cmic.getCMICIs("GetCurrentDataVer1"));
            DatacenterDataVer1 dataSet = response.getGetCurrentDataVer1Result();

            List products = dataSet.getAProductBase().getProductBase();
            // print some primary keys to show data being processed.
            for(Iterator<ProductBase> iter = products.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
                ProductBase pb = iter.next();
                System.out.println(pb.getPkID());
            }

        } catch (JAXBException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }


    }
```

The class generated by Netbeans.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "getCurrentDataVer1Result"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "GetCurrentDataVer1Response", namespace = "http://www.cmicdataservices.com/")
public class GetCurrentDataVer1Response {

    @XmlElement(name = "GetCurrentDataVer1Result")
    protected DatacenterDataVer1 getCurrentDataVer1Result;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the getCurrentDataVer1Result property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link DatacenterDataVer1 }
     *     
     */
    public DatacenterDataVer1 getGetCurrentDataVer1Result() {
        return getCurrentDataVer1Result;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the getCurrentDataVer1Result property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link DatacenterDataVer1 }
     *     
     */
    public void setGetCurrentDataVer1Result(DatacenterDataVer1 value) {
        this.getCurrentDataVer1Result = value;
    }

}
```

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5044042/jaxb-ignore-element

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of different options:

**Option #1**

If you receive the XML input as an `InputStream` you could parse it with StAX and get an `XMLStreamReader`.  You could then advance the `XMLStreamReader` to the local root element you want to unmarshal and have JAXB unmarshal it.

**Option #2**

You could use the [`javax.xml.xpath`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html) library to select the local root element that you want to unmarshal with JAXB.  For a javax.xml.xpath example see:

- [splitting up of xml file using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566124/splitting-up-of-xml-file-using-java/5566161#5566161)