# Creating an RSS feed from Java Backend

Tags: java, drupal, rss

Basically what I would like to achieve....

I want to be able from my java backend where I can update an RSS feed and it be displayed on my webpage..

for instance it will kind of act like a newsfeed and will tick along nicely with updates.

is this possible or is there a better way of doing this

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at this question [How to write an RSS feed with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113063/java-rss-library)

I'm an advocate of using established, reputable libraries rather than reinventing the wheel wherever possible.