# What are good scala libraries to generate RSS feeds?

Tags: scala, rss, playframework-2.0

Is there any scala library that can be used to generate RSS Feeds using idiomatic features like case classes? Even better if it provides helpers for using with Play framework.

Comment: For JAva, take a look at Rome: http://rometools.org/

Comment: If you look for java, duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113063/java-rss-library

Answer (score 11):

Well, the embedded XML DSL is an idiomatic (if somewhat lambasted) feature, so I don't see why you'd need any library support. Just take a bit of RSS XML, which is valid Scala, and put in some variable content:

```
val myRss = 
  <rss version="2.0">

  <channel>
  <title>An example RSS feed</title>
  <description>La dee daah</description>
  <link>http://www.example.com/rss</link>
  <lastBuildDate>Mon, 05 Oct 2012 11:12:55 =0100 </lastBuildDate>
  <pubDate>Tue, 06 Oct 2012 09:00:00 +0100</pubDate>


  {
    for (itemTitle <- List("foo", "bar", "baz")) yield {
      <item>
        <title>{itemTitle}</title>
        <description>This is an example of an Item</description>
        <link>http://www.example.com/item</link>
        <guid isPermaLink="false">123</guid>
        <pubDate>Tue, 06 Oct 2012 13:00:00 +0100</pubDate>
      </item>
    }
  }

</channel>
</rss>
```